# Как вычислить координаты всех точек лежащих на окружности

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предположим мне нужны координаты 360 точек на окружности, по одной на каждый градус поворота

Есть предположение:

```
int x = (int)Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * i / n) * R + x[0];
int y = (int)Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * i / n) * R + y[0];
```

Где i - номер точки, n - кол-во точек = 360, R - радиус, x[0] и y[0] - координаты центра окружности

Вот только таким способом вычисляются только эти четыре точки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как пройтись по всем 360-ти точкам?

Comment: вы сами кастуете в int, он не может принимать значения с плавающей запятой (а именно они вам и нужны).

Comment: работает, спасибо.
час просидел,
как обычно в общем

Comment: @zakihatfild, вы бы приложили ответ, вдруг кто не поймёт )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> int x = (int)Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * i / n) * R + x[0];
> int y = (int)Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * i / n) * R + y[0];
> ```

Я предполагаю, что нужны именно целочисленные координаты. В таком случае следует выполнять округление после умножения на радиус.

```
int x = (int)(Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * i / n) * R + 0.5) + x0;
int y = (int)(Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * i / n) * R + 0.5) + y0;
```

Это по-прежнему не гарантирует, что получатся все 360 точек, но теперь их не всегда будет 4.

http://ideone.com/fxzB8V

```
4 of 360 when radius is 1
76 of 360 when radius is 10
140 of 360 when radius is 20
268 of 360 when radius is 40
356 of 360 when radius is 80
360 of 360 when radius is 90
360 of 360 when radius is 100
```

Если же целочисленные координаты не требуются, то вместо int следует использовать double:

```
double x = Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * i / n) * R + x0;
double y = Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * i / n) * R + y0;
```

Comment: И что этот ответ значит? Каким образом смещение центра окружности на 0,5 должно решить сформулированную проблему?

Comment: @KromStern, я не смещаю центр. Я поставил скобки, чтобы округление происходило после умножения на радиус, а не до. `+ 0.5` тоже в скобках и обеспечивает математическое округление вместо отбрасывания дробной части.

Comment: даже если вы примените математическое округление, это все равно выдаст всего несколько точек, а не 360, как нужно автору. Смотрите комментарий Etki.

Comment: @KromStern, нет, число точек будет зависеть от радиуса. Я исходил из предположения, что ему нужны целые координаты, например, для отрисовки на Bitmap'е. http://ideone.com/fxzB8V

Comment: Совершенно верно, и судя по примеру, радиус = 1.

Comment: @KromStern, в его коде округляется результат вызова sin и cos, поэтому у него 4 точки независимо от радиуса. А в моём округляется конечная координата, поэтому число точек будет соответствующим радиусу. Именно в этом заключается исправление.

Comment: @KromStern, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Если речь идёт о C#, более идиоматическое округление — через `Math.Round`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int r = 5;

for(int i = 0 ; i < 360; i++)
{
    double rad = (double)i / 180 * 3.14;
    double x = r * cos(rad);
    double y = r * sin(rad);

    qDebug() << "X:" << x << " Y:" << y << " Rad:" << rad;
}
```

это решение на qt c++, так как visual studio нет под рукой.
К получившимся x,y добавляется значение смещения центра. r - радиус окружности

Вывод примерно такой:

```
 X: 5  Y: 0  Rad: 0
 X: 4.99924  Y: 0.0872178  Rad: 0.0174444
 X: 4.99696  Y: 0.174409  Rad: 0.0348889
 X: 4.99315  Y: 0.261547  Rad: 0.0523333
 X: 4.98783  Y: 0.348606  Rad: 0.0697778
 X: 4.98099  Y: 0.435558  Rad: 0.0872222
 X: 4.97264  Y: 0.522378  Rad: 0.104667
 X: 4.96277  Y: 0.609039  Rad: 0.122111
 X: 4.95139  Y: 0.695515  Rad: 0.139556
 X: 4.9385  Y: 0.781779  Rad: 0.157
 X: 4.92412  Y: 0.867805  Rad: 0.174444
 ....
```